# Working with child nodes in subroutine (XML::LibXML)

Tags: xml, perl

In my little piece of code I parse some XML data, but since I need to do the same thing in 3 places, I would like to make a subroutine for each time. But I need to pass the current node I'm working on as an argument, being beyond my current skills to access the current node's child nodes.

Here's an example of my code:

```
foreach $day ($doc->findnodes('/my/current/path')) {

  @atts = $day->getAttributes();

  foreach $at (@atts) {

    $na = $at->getName();
    $va = $at->getValue();

    if ($va eq "today") {

      #------ my repeated code begins here -----
      foreach $thing ($day->findnodes('child_nodes_im_looking_for')) {

        #----- do a lot of stuff
      }

      #------ my repeated code ends here -----
    }

    if ($va eq "tomorrow") {

      #same repeated code
    }

    if ($va eq "some_other_day") {

      #same repeated code.... again
    }

    #for other days... do nothing

  }
```

How should I pass my current node to the subroutine so I can access its child nodes directly from the routine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I trust you have `use strict` and `use warnings` in effect? Even if you have, you should declare your variables with `my` as *late* as possible, ideally at their first point of use.

I'm unclear exactly what the problem is as, on the face of it, you just need to pass the node `$day` as a normal subroutine parameter.

This refactoring of your code sample shows the idea. If I have misunderstood you then please say so.

```
for my $day ($doc->findnodes('/my/current/path')) {

  my @atts = $day->getAttributes();

  for my $att (@atts) {

    my $na = $att->getName;
    my $va = $att->getValue;

    if ($va eq 'today') {
      repeated_code($day);
    }

    if ($va eq 'tomorrow') {
      repeated_code($day);
    }

    if ($va eq 'some_other_day') {
      repeated_code($day);
    }

    # for other days... do nothing

  }
}

sub repeated_code {
  my ($node) = @_;

  for my $thing ($node->findnodes('child_nodes_im_looking_for')) {

    #----- do a lot of stuff
  }

}
```

Comment: Why do I always see how dumb my question was after seeing the answer?
... sigh...

Thanks for clearing that up, I also noted I should use the following line to clean the code up a bit:

`if (($va eq 'today') || ($va eq 'tomorrow') || ($va eq 'some_other_day')) {
      repeated_code($day);
}`

Comment: @Ockie: It is wrong to berate yourself: there is no *dumb* unless it is deliberate